# Localizations and colimits

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory

My question is regarding a part of a proof. This is what is written:

[image]

So my question is the following: If we every element outside of $x$ is mapped to a unit in a finite stage of the colimit, how can one formally say what that means for the map into the actual colimit, i.e. how do I know that every element outside of $x$ is mapped to a unit in the colimit? Thanks in advance!

Maybe i add another question regarding the end. I dont really understand how the argument there works. Shouldnt we take an arbitrary map  from A to B that takes all f outside of x to units and then conclude that this factors through the colimit, i.e. the colimit fullfills the universal property of the localization? Or maybe we do that im not sure.

Comment: You can think of elements of the colimit as "coherent sequences" of elements at every stage. If the "mapped to a unit" property holds at *every* stage of the colimit, then you just want to verify that a coherent sequence whose members are all units is itself a unit of the colimit.

Comment: @TabesBridges it's not true that every element not in $x$ gets mapped to a unit in _every_ stage of the colimit. (Think $f=1$ for example). But it is actually sufficient that it is mapped to a unit at _some_ stage. Also you're confusing colimits and (inverse) limits here: elements of an inverse limits are coherent sequences.

Comment: Just to emphasize the point: elements of a *limit* should be thought of as things defined "at all stages", whereas elements of a colimit should be thought of as things defined "at some stage".

Comment: Ah that is very interesting as well , thank you @Brian Shin

Comment: My pleasure! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Lemma.** Let $\phi: A \to B$ be a ring homomorphisms. If $f \in A$ is a unit, then $\phi(f)$ is a unit.

In the particular situation, for any $f_0 \in A$ with $x \in D_{f_0}$, we have that the canonical morphism $A \to \operatorname*{colim}_{x \in D_f} A[1/f]$ factors through $A[1/f_0]$. In other words, we have morphisms
$$ A \to A[1/f_0] \to \operatorname*{colim}_{x \in D_f} A[1/f].$$
By construction, $f_0 \in A$ is invertible in $A[1/f_0]$, and it is invertible in the colimit because of the lemma.

Heuristically, if we have an element that is invertible at some "finite stage", it will be invertible for any "later stage", including the "stage at infinity".

Comment: Uhh true that lemma is so obvious i cant believe i have not thought of it. Thanks so much!